# An issue with Drawing a line on python

Tags: python, pygame

In general, I need to draw a line from the point to the current mouse coordinates when the left button is pressed so that the length of the line increases (like an animation). But I can't find the error that caused everything to work incorrectly. In the left part of the screen, the line is drawn instantly, in the right part it is drawn with a delay, and if the mouse cursor is positioned horizontally, it is drawn normally with animation. There is a video where i show my problem. (https://vimeo.com/641966235)

```
import pygame, sys, threading, os
from math import sin, cos

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
pygame.display.set_caption("loading")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 500
y = 500
x2 = 5
y2 = 5
start = [x, y]
step = [x2, y2]
end = [x, y]

while True:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

   mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
   screen.fill("#0d0e2e")

   if pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (1, 0, 0):

       if end[0] >= mouse_x:
           end[0] = mouse_x

       end[0] += step[0]

       if end[1] >= mouse_y:
           end[1] = mouse_y

       end[1] += step[1]

   else:
       end[0] = x 
       end[1] = y

   pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 169, 255), start, end, 12)

   print(str(mouse_x) + " " + str(mouse_y))
   pygame.display.update()
   clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to draw a line from the "start" to "end" with animation.

the final position of the "end" will be the mouse position

that means:

```
end_x = mouse_x
end_y = mouse_y
```

and the equation can be written as:

```
l = 1.0
end_x = start_x + l * (mouse_x - start_x)
end_y = start_y + l * (mouse_y - start_y)
```

(mouse_x - start_x), (mouse_y - start_y) is the vector from the "start" to the mouse position.
https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html

you could change the length of this vector by controlling the "l"

by accumulating the "l" from 0.0 to 1.0, the "end" will be moving forward to the "mouse position"

Here is the demonstration according to the code you provided:

```
import pygame, sys, threading, os
from math import sin, cos

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
pygame.display.set_caption("loading")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 500
y = 500
x2 = 5
y2 = 5
start = [x, y]
step = [0.0, 0.0]
end = [x, y]

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.fill("#0d0e2e")
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (1, 0, 0):
        end[0] = start[0] + step[0] * (mouse_x - start[0])
        end[1] = start[1] + step[1] * (mouse_y - start[1])
        step[0] += 0.1
        step[1] += 0.1
        step[0] = min(1.0, step[0])
        step[1] = min(1.0, step[1])
    else:
        step[0] = 0
        step[1] = 0
        end[0] = x 
        end[1] = y

    pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 169, 255), start, end, 12)

    print(str(mouse_x) + " " + str(mouse_y))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Thank u so much :)